# Spring Thymeleaf th:src

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

```
<img th:if = "${person.getImage() != null}" th:src = "@{/images/${image}}">
```

Если пишу так , то картинка не загружается (image - Название картинки String)

```
<img th:if = "${person.getImage() != null}" th:src = "@{/images/Название}">
```

А если  так , то все работает
Что делать ?

Comment: В модель передали то image? И помойму там синтаксис вставки в юрл переменной немного другой, хотя могу ошибаться,  нет возможности проверить

Comment: Да, image в модель вставлен